# How can I remove a stuck cam sensor on my 2007 Chevy Avalanche?

Tags: chevrolet, avalanche, camshaft-position-sensor

I have a 5.3L V8 Chevrolet Avalanche, and the faulty cam sensor is stuck. I can't remove it in order to replace it.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How is it stuck? What have you tried to get it out? This engine has it in the front timing cover, correct? I would assume it's the 5.3L V8?

Comment: Yes it's a v8 .

Comment: It broke of in there actually because it was so old I'm assuming

Answer (score 1):

If it's stuck and you have a replacement for it, it doesn't really matter *how you get it out*. The sensor is broken and will be replaced. If it were me and it was stuck, I'd grab it with a pair of Vice Grips or channel lock pliers and crank it out of there. Your first move is to twist it in the bore to ge it moving, then you should be able to work it out after you've broken it free. Ensure you've cleaned the bore once you have it out so it is spotless. Then put a dab of grease on both the bore and on the o-ring of the sensor. You don't want the o-ring to get caught on something and be damaged. Also, don't use the bolt and tab to draw the new sensor into the bore, make sure it is fully seated before you put the bolt in place. If the sensor is not fully seated, it may not pick up the signal from the cam shaft sprocket, so make sure it is fully seated. After that, attach the wiring harness and you should be golden.